# Android GearVR, how to run the camera live view instead of playing videos or showing image?

Tags: android, gear-vr

how to run the camera live view instead of playing videos or showing image in GearVR ?

I tried with gearvrf sdk, but i am getting camera view is null. please guide me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
GVRCameraSceneObject cameraObject = null;
    try {
        cameraObject = new GVRCameraSceneObject(gvrContext, 3.6f, 2.0f);
        cameraObject.setUpCameraForVrMode(1); // set up 60 fps camera preview.
    } catch (GVRCameraSceneObject.GVRCameraAccessException e) {
        // Cannot open camera
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot open the camera",e);
    }
cameraObject.getTransform().setPosition(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
scene.getMainCameraRig().addChildObject(object);
```

Put this code into your GVRMain in onInit method. Obviously you should initialize your scene object